# null in Enum in Java

Tags: java, spring, enums

I have 3 enum types for a functionality in my controller. Also, have set proper checks on UI. BUT, if someone tests the API with a value equal to null then I don't know how to handle that.

Here's the code:

```
public enum AuthStatus implements Comparable<AuthStatus> {
    ABC("test", "testtt", -1), 
    DEF("tesds", "dsds", 0), 
    .
    .
```

If ABC or DEF in given in the payload, everything works fine, what to do if nothing is given in payload,i.e. "".

Basically, I want to add "" as an enum type, eg:

```
ABC("test", "testtt", 2), 
DEF("tesds", "dsds", 0), 
""("invalid", "Not Valid", -1) // What should be replaced by "".
```

Comment: How is this enum used? An enum type of `""` doesn't make sense.

Comment: You show treat it as invalid and not add an enum

Comment: You could use `NULL("invalid", "Not Valid", -1)` (in uppercase, this should be fine). But this is not a `null` enum, just an enum named `NULL`. Of course, `UNKNOWN`, `INVALID`,  `ERROR`, ... are valid name for this too...

Answer (score 2):

Enum names have to be valid Java identifiers, and there is no valid Java identifier that has zero characters length.

If you want to match input against some value, then using a Java enum name to express that is not a good idea, as there are many more limitation to Java identifiers (can't contain spaces nor many other characters). You should add another field to your enum, you could call it `matchValue`, and match your input against that value rather than against the enum name.

```
public enum AuthStatus implements Comparable<AuthStatus> {
    ABC("ABC", "test", "testtt", -1), 
    INVALID("", "invalid", "Not Valid", -1);

    private final String matchValue;

    private AuthStatus(String matchValue, ...) {
        this.matchValue = matchValue;
    }
}
```